# how to iterate with Linq to create list of objets?

Tags: c#, list, linq, umbraco

I'm trying to iterate from a list with Linq in order to create and return a model, with contains a list of item and a quantity of total items.

The object that must be returned is as following:

```
public class ListeArticlesModel
    {        
        public List<TuileArticleModel> Items { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm currently stuck with this :

```
result.Actualites = tousLesArticlesFromDb
                .ToList()
                .Where(
                    a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
                             .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites)
                .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
                .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage)
                .Select(
                    a => new ListeArticlesModel
                    {
                        Items = new List<TuileArticleModel>
                        {
                            // returns a TuileArticleModel 
                            getItem(a)
                        },
                    })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is not what I want. If I remove the .FirstOrDefault() I get an IEnumerable

I know I am missing something. I'm building a new ListeArticleModel for each "a" item and then I just take the first one built but I don't see how to get out of here...

(ps : I graduated a few weeks ago. I am new to C#. I know it may be basics. I am trying to learn them :D)

I tried this:

```
var actus = tousLesArticlesFromDb
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(
                        a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
                                 .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites)
                    .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
                    .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage);
```

This gives me an IEnumerable (using umbraco here) which contains the `criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage` IPublishedContent items of type "Actualites" that I want...

Now, for each I'd like to create a new `TuileArticleModel` to feed the `Items` proptery (a `List<TuileArticleModel>`) of my `result.Actualites`...

EDIT :

I think I just resolved my problem by exposing it to you guys, and reading the comments. So I did this :

```
 var actus = tousLesArticlesFromDb
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(
                        a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
                                 .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites)
                    .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage);

                result.Actualites.Items = actus.Select(a => {return getItem(a); }).ToList();
```

or in one statement :

```
  result.Actualites = new ListeArticlesModel
                {
                    Items = tousLesArticlesFromDb
                            .Where
                            (
                                a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
                                         .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites
                            )
                            .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
                            .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage)
                            .Select(a => { return getItem(a); }).ToList(),
                };
```

Comment: I think a [mcve] that properly shows what kind of source data you have (or something that mimics it enough), and what you get with your approach v what you want to get might help

Comment: Have you tried putting .ToList() at the end of the function?

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer i tied but it returned me an IEnumerable<ListeArticleModel>. But I was doing it wrong all the way, anyway... :)

Comment: you just have to remove the .ToList() after tousLesArticlesFromDb  the ToList bringing all the data in memory and then querying it which defeats the point of a query. Removing .ToList() and .FirstOrDefault will give you an iqueryable of the select statement you want ot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the resultset first:

```
var results = tousLesArticlesFromDb
    .Where
    (
        a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
              .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites
    )
    .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
    .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage);
```

Then pass it into the new object:

```
result.Actualites = new ListeArticlesModel
    {
        Items = results.ToList()
    };
```

Or, if you want to do it all in one statement:

```
result.Actualites = new ListeArticlesModel
{
    Items = tousLesArticlesFromDb
        .Where
        (
            a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("ficheArticle_typeDeContenu")
                  .FirstOrDefault()?.Name == @EnumResources.TypeDeContenu_Actualites
        )
        .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
        .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage);
        .ToList()
};
```

Comment: thanks, i think i found a solution that looks like the one you gave. does it miss something for the one in full statement? I don't understand what happens between the Take(); and the ToListe()...?

Comment: I usd your one statement solution to my purpose. I've Edited my post so you can see the result of you help :) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
.ToList()
```

instead of

```
.FirstOrDefault()
```

Another thing to note is

```
tousLesArticlesFromDb
                .Where( *** )
                .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
                .Take(criteriaModel.NbrItemsParPage)
                .Select(
                    a => new ListeArticlesModel
                    {
                        Items = new List<TuileArticleModel>
                        {
                            // returns a TuileArticleModel 
                            getItem(a)
                        },
                    })
```

This will return a `IQueryable`, no processing has been done yet, you've just created the query for it.

Calling `.ToList()` will execute the `IQueryable` and return the result as a list.

Comment: Actually this wont' return iqueryable at all. See the .ToList() after tousLesArticlesFromDb that is getting all the data from db and doing the quries on the memory after that

Comment: @npo Whoops, I saw that and meant to edit it out if my answer.